How can I save and load header information of FITS files suing pickle?
Background
I want to convert the header information of a FITS data into a dictionary and save it as a binary file using Python. And of course, the binary data has to be loaded later.
Problem
The dictionary of FITS header data saved as a pickle file cannot be loaded, and I want to know how to fix this.
Here is the minimal reproducible example and the error message.
import astropy.io.fits as fits
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle

cwd = os.getcwd()
fits_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'hmi.M_45s.20200101_020130_TAI.2.magnetogram.fits')
path = os.path.join(cwd, 'demo.pkl')
hdul = fits.open(fits_path)
hdul.verify('silentfix')
print(hdul.info())
# hdul[0] is often the primary Header Data Unit (HDU) and hdul[1] is the first extension HDU
hdr = dict(hdul[1].header)
hdr['COMMENT'] = str(hdr['COMMENT'])
img  = np.transpose(hdul[1].data)
hdul.close()

with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(hdr, f)
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    hdr_loaded = pickle.load(f)

Filename: cwd\hmi.M_45s.20200101_020130_TAI.2.magnetogram.fits
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU       6   ()
  1  COMPRESSED_IMAGE    1 CompImageHDU    114   (4096, 4096)   int32
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 21
     19     pickle.dump(hdr, f)
     20 with open(path, 'rb') as f:
---> 21     hdr_loaded = pickle.load(f)

TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'table_header'

With my environment (python 3.9.18), dumping and loading of img work fine, while they don't for hdr.
You can download the FITS data provided by the Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI) onboard the Solar Dynamic Observatory (SDO) from here, by entring
hmi.M_45s[2020.01.01_02:01:30_TAI]

to the "RecordSet" and providing your email address in the "Notify". Then click "check parameters" and "submit". A link to download the data will be shown in a while.
What I Searched
I guessed that the issue is related to FITS data. Also I found a similar problem Pickling an astropy.io.fits.CompImageHDU fails, but I am not sure how to fix my code.

My apologies, but why do you need to save as a .pickle file? I normally just keep everything as fits, instead of trying to convert to a different file format.

My original code loads many .fits files once and saves the image and header information as lists. The image list and the header list are saved as .pkl files. To avoid this problem related to the .fits file header, I can create a dictionary containing the necessary items from the header information. Do you have a good routine, for example, when analysing time series .fits files?

When analyzing images from SDO, I normally use SunPy MapSequences to load and save image sequences. Have you tried SunPy at all?

Surprisingly, this is my first time using SunPy properly, but this MapSequences looks very useful. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Is there a reason you're doing dict(hdul[1].header)? Superficially that might work, but if the result really just container key/value pairs where the values are Python primitive types pickling would be no problem. Without more of a traceback I couldn't say but it looks like your dict might contain some values that aren't meaningful when disassociated from the header they belonged to. I know at various points I've fixed bugs with pickling headers so why not just pickle it directly without this dict() wrapping? Alternatively just write the header as a string.

I often rely on my supervisor's code, which handles headers as dictionaries. This is why I tried to convert the header to a dictionary. Your ideas about saving the headers are interesting. This is my second time seeking help here, and I found the responses really helpful! I checked the data types of the header converted to the dictionary, and there was a 'astropy.io.fits.header._HeaderCommentaryCards' object. The saving and loading as a dictionary worked when I removed this.

Let me briefly share how I avoided the error.
I looked into the datatypes of values in hdr and found a value with 'astropy.io.fits.header._HeaderCommentaryCards' datatype for the keyword 'HISTORY'.
.
.
CAMERA <class 'int'>
BUNIT <class 'str'>
ORIGIN <class 'str'>
CONTENT <class 'str'>
QUALITY <class 'int'>
QUALLEV1 <class 'int'>
HISTORY <class 'astropy.io.fits.header._HeaderCommentaryCards'>
COMMENT <class 'str'>
BLD_VERS <class 'str'>
HCAMID <class 'int'>
SOURCE <class 'str'>
.
.

It seems that 'COMMENT' originally takes a value with the same datatype.
I removed the items with this datatype, and the saving and loading process worked.
This solution looks a bit cheating because I just discarded the part causing the trouble. I did this as the problem needed to be fixed quickly, and I don't need the 'HISTORY' information right now.
